# Eliminar filas sin datos en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

trato de hacer una consulta donde se eliminan las filas que no tienen datos, en este caso es 1, 13 y 14. No he podido dar con el chiste.

He llegado hasta F IS NOT NULL pero no logro avanzar de ahi, alguna recomendacion?

```
SELECT *
FROM [Zion_StagingArea].[dbo].[DWH_SHCPAID_CAPITATEDS]
WHERE F1 NOT LIKE 'Program:%'
AND (F2 IS NOT NULL OR F3 IS NOT NULL OR F4 IS NOT NULL OR F5 IS NOT NULL OR F6 IS NOT NULL OR F7 IS NOT NULL OR F8 IS NOT NULL OR F9 IS NOT NULL OR F10 IS NOT NULL OR F11 IS NOT NULL OR F12 IS NOT NULL OR F13 IS NOT NULL)
```

Esta es la imagen de la consulta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria arreglarla?

Comment: Primero que nada... 13 tiene datos en la columna F16, eso no cuenta?? Y segundo... creo que lo estás planteando un poco al revés. Estás haciendo que seleccione filas donde **ALGUNO** de los campos **TENGA** valor. Eso no significa que esté vacío... es justo al revés!

Comment: Pareciera que se trata de alguna importación de algún reporte y buscas eliminar los totales, yo te sugiero, si hay alguna columna en la que seguro tienes que tener datos, preguntes por la misma, por ejemplo `WHERE NULLIF(F1, '') IS NULL`, la idea del `NULLIF` es hacer `NULL`  la columna que en este caso tiene algún blanco, si tiene espacios deberías "trimearlos" antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que quieres filtrar los datos en base a tu consulta:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Zion_StagingArea].[dbo].[DWH_SHCPAID_CAPITATEDS]
WHERE F1 NOT LIKE 'Program:%'
AND (F2 IS NOT NULL OR F3 IS NOT NULL OR F4 IS NOT NULL OR F5 IS NOT NULL OR F6 IS NOT NULL OR F7 IS NOT NULL OR F8 IS NOT NULL OR F9 IS NOT NULL OR F10 IS NOT NULL OR F11 IS NOT NULL OR F12 IS NOT NULL OR F13 IS NOT NULL)
```

puedes realizar una subconsulta:

```sql
select 
  * 
from
(
SELECT *
FROM [Zion_StagingArea].[dbo].[DWH_SHCPAID_CAPITATEDS]
WHERE F1 NOT LIKE 'Program:%'
AND (F2 IS NOT NULL OR F3 IS NOT NULL OR F4 IS NOT NULL OR F5 IS NOT NULL OR F6 IS NOT NULL OR F7 IS NOT NULL OR F8 IS NOT NULL OR F9 IS NOT NULL OR F10 IS NOT NULL OR F11 IS NOT NULL OR F12 IS NOT NULL OR F13 IS NOT NULL)
) as res
where 
  res.F1 is not null 
  and res.F13 is not null 
  and res.F14 is not null
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos